# Can more than 1 user log onto a single AWS Linux EC2 instance? (Beginner)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Sorry, I'm a complete newb to AWS. Taking the AWS Essentials course at end of the month. I have a very basic question: can 2 or more different AWS account holders log onto a single AWS Linux EC2 instance at the same time and work as 2 or more separate Linux users on that same EC2 instance? For example, we want to run RStudio Server Pro on an EC2 Linux instance and have 2 or more people use RStudio at the same time for different analyses from the same EC2 instance.

I just had a call with an AWS Solutions Architect and I was surprised that he said he did not know the answer. I searched the web and StackExchange sites but haven't been able to find an answer. I was under the impression that an EC2 Linux instance is basically like running a Linux server remotely and on an Linux server, you can obviously have more than 1 user logged in simultaneously. However, I'm not sure if EC2 instances work the same way. Thanks and sorry if this basic question is answered elsewhere.

Comment: @mdpc Any suggestions on which Stack Exchange site is more appropriate, if any? Further, with respect to "hire a professional to help you out", I assumed the AWS Solutions Architect was a "professional" so since he couldn't answer it, I assumed it was worthy of a "professional" site. Perhaps that was too presumptuous. We are in the process of a hiring a SysAdmin / AWS SysOps full-time. I'll also try to edit the question.

Comment: The AWS Solutions Architects aren't really for questions on the nitty-gritty of how to run a Linux box, they're higher level stuff - which AWS services to use for what, how to link them together. They're there to answer questions like "what would I use Amazon S3 for?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. More than one person can SSH into the same account at the same time, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you can even remove the SSH block for logging in as root (if you try to log in as root, it'll reply "Please log in as ec2-user" and disconnect).

Comment: Doing so is a bad idea and should be avoided.